# Literal white noise

Tags: noise, computer-architecture

My friend has a work desktop computer with some non-fancy hardware. The onboard audio is output via a 3.5mm cable to some speakers in the room. These speakers produce a constant hum while the computer is on, presumably because of the slight interference.

The fun part is that the hum is not constant. Different tasks on the computer result in different noise levels. After playing around, he isolated it to the proportion of white on the screen. Example: he opens a single File Explorer window. He grabs the corner and stretches it. The volume of the hum is directly correlated to the size of the window, which is both hilarious and frustrating.

My question is, what is the physical mechanism behind this? I assume it has to do with increased power draw from the monitor to show the brighter colours. But how does that turn into hum?

**Edit:** Got more info. It's [an LED monitor](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/led-monitor-sa450-series). Power is grounded three-prong into a power bar that is also three-prong into the wall. The audio cable (here's the big clue, I assume) was broken at one point and soldered together.

Comment: VGA or HDMI or what? LCD with backlight or LED display? Both may be significant. [Edit] the details into your question.

Comment: Ungrounded two-prong power supplies used? Devices with grounded plugs  devices connected to ungrouded outlets so they are ungrounded? Is there a ground loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Increased power draw doesn't just mean that the power draw goes up from one steady value to another. In reality, the power drawn by the computer and monitor are spiky, often with repeating patterns. In the case of the monitor, the spikes in power usage might be synchronized with the time it takes to draw a line of the screen, as well as the monitor's refresh rate.

As for the physical mechanism of the power draw being coupled to the speakers, it's necessary to consider how power is delivered to components -- through wires, ground planes, and traces, all of which have an impedance associated with them. The noisy, spiky power draw can couple through these nets, inducing noise on the ground and power lines at the sound-card and speaker; as a consequence the coupled noise on these supply rails leads to spurious sounds from the speakers. Another, possibly more likely culprit, is damaged cables (either in the sound path or the video path) -- if their ground wires/pins are missing and damaged, then this supply noise will be far more likely to couple to/from the *signal* path.

The use of proper decoupling capacitors and other factors is supposed to reduce this, but cheaply-made or damaged power supplies and components may not properly filter the ground noise, resulting in what you observe.